# Ionic 2 img in ngStyle in html wont show up on device

Tags: angular, ionic2

My image is located in `src/assets/img/background.png`

in my html which is located in `src/pages/myPage/myPage.html`. I try to set a background image like so

```
<div [ngStyle]="{
      'background-image': 'url(assets/img/background.png)'
    }">
</div>
```

I need the `[ngStyle]=""` because I am dynamically setting the background image inside an `*ngFor` based off a property in a json object

I have also tried

`'background-image': 'url(../assets/img/background.png)'`

`'background-image': 'url(./assets/img/background.png)'`

`'background-image': 'url(/assets/img/background.png)'`

I have also been google-ing and I came across [this](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/background-image-for-page-on-ionic-2/52466) but I still can't get it to work on my device (Galaxy S6)

However, they show up when I serve using `ionic serve` and emulate using `ionic emulate android --livereload`

Also, **this works**, in my `.scss` in `src/pages/myPage/myPage.scss` I can get a background image to show up like

```
.myClass {
    background-image: url(../assets/img/background.png)
}
```

Please help!

Comment: Try `background-image': 'url(./assets/img/..)`

Comment: That didn't work either :(

Comment: its not the code..what steps are you taking to run in a device?

Comment: I run `ionic build android --prod` then I put the `.apk` in drop box and install on phone

Comment: Ok and with `background-image: url(./assets/img/..)`

Comment: no..use the one which worked for you in serve/emulate

Comment: Ok, I will try later today when I get home from work

Comment: I got it figured out thanks to [this](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/resources/developer-tips/#debugging-android-chrome). It was a path issue, it was looking for a folder with a capitalized letter and on the computer the folder is all lower case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was able to debug the emulator with [this](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/resources/developer-tips/#debugging-android-chrome) and I found out that is was looking for the image on a path that looked like this

`assets/img/Backgrounds/background.png`

and it should have been like this

`assets/img/backgrounds/background.png`